# Fatal error in launcher: When Check pip Version

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When i check pip version to install pandas in Python 3.6.6 show below error..
I am beginner for python Please can tell me how to solve that error?

C:\python36\Scripts>pip -V

'Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python36_64\python.exe"  "C:\python36\Scripts\pip.exe" -V': ??????????????????'

when upgrade pip show Requirement already satisfied

C:\python36>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (20.3.1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `c:\python36_64\python.exe` exist? I'm noting your python path and your pip path are different. You also call python from the non `_64` folder the 2nd time.

Comment: @Loocid c:\python36_64\python.exe not exit in my folder